# GloH20 Global Koppen Geiger Raster Values

Tags: raster, land-classification, global

I am trying to use the global KG classification raster from http://www.gloh2o.org/koppen/. Everything seems to be working fine, but the values from the raster seem to range from 0 - 30, however the legend provided by the team only defines values from 1 - 30 so I'm wondering what the 0 value is supposed to signify. I'm guessing this is supposed to be a NaN value but I'm not sure how to verify this, I've contacted the team but have had no response for a couple of weeks.

Comment: I suspect 0 is for points in the ocean, but it would be useful if this was clarified in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used the raster dataset as well and was confronted with the same question. As the A. Bollans already explained, the zeros can be interpreted as missing values, i.e., no climate classification present which should be mostly (or only) found in large water bodies.